# How do I get a web page to remember it's state

Tags: jquery, state

i'm trying to get a web page to remember it's state, so that if a user leaves OR refreshes the page the point they have reached isn't lost. I've tried a LOT of different ways and just can't seem to get them to work.

I've attached a `FIDDLE` to demonstrate the code. I just need some MAJOR help figuring out how to achieve some sort of memory for a web page :/

CODE:
**HTML:**

```
<form method="post" id="partnumbers" name="partnumbers" action="formHandler">
<div id="specialOffer">
<ul>
    <li>
    <div id="prodD">
        <input type="hidden" name="partNum_1" id="catnum1" value="" />
        <div id="close" style="display:none;"><a href="#">Remove X</a></div>
        <div id="Prod1"></div>
    </div>
    </li>
    <li>
    <div id="prodO">
        <input type="hidden" name="partNum_2" id="catnum2" value="" />
        <div id="close" style="display:none;"><a href="#">Remove X</a></div>
        <div id="Prod2"></div>
    </div>
    </li>
    <li>
    <div id="prodA">
        <input type="hidden" name="partNum_3" id="catnum3" value="" />
        <div id="close" style="display:none;"><a href="#">Remove X</a></div>
        <div id="Prod3"></div>
    </div>
    </li>
    <li>
    <div id="prodSubmit">
        <input name="Submit" id="Submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />

    </div>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>

<div id="flyout1">
<ul class="paginate-1">
    <li><div id="subProd" class="9059863">
    <img class="thumb" src="images/placeholder.jpg" width="110" height="110" />
    <span class="product">
    <p class="title">PRODUCT TITLE</p>
        <p class="number">PARTnum</p>
        <p class="price">Price</p>
    </span>
    <a href="#" class="button">+ Add item</a>
        <a href="http://www.google.co.uk" class="qv"><img src="images/qv.png" width="17" height="17" /></a>
</div></li>
    <li><div id="subProd" class="9087361">
    <img class="thumb" src="images/placeholder.jpg" width="110" height="110" />
    <span class="product">
    <p class="title">PRODUCT TITLE</p>
        <p class="number">PARTnum</p>
        <p class="price">Price</p>
    </span>
    <a href="#" class="button">+ Add item</a>
    <a href="http://www.google.co.uk" class="qv"><img src="images/qv.png" width="17" height="17" /></a>
</div></li>
    <li><div id="subProd" class="9087378">
    <img class="thumb" src="images/placeholder.jpg" width="110" height="110" />
    <span class="product">
    <p class="title">PRODUCT TITLE</p>
        <p class="number">PARTnum</p>
        <p class="price">Price</p>
    </span>
    <a href="#" class="button">+ Add item</a>
    <a href="http://www.google.co.uk" class="qv"><img src="images/qv.png" width="17" height="17" /></a>
</div></li>
    <li><div id="subProd" class="9087354">
    <img class="thumb" src="images/placeholder.jpg" width="110" height="110" />
    <span class="product">
    <p class="title">PRODUCT TITLE</p>
        <p class="number">PARTnum</p>
        <p class="price">Price</p>
    </span>
    <a href="#" class="button">+ Add item</a>
        <a href="http://www.google.co.uk" class="qv"><img src="images/qv.png" width="17" height="17" /></a>
</div></li>
    <li><div id="subProd" class="9059791">
    <img class="thumb" src="images/placeholder.jpg" width="110" height="110" />
    <span class="product">
    <p class="title">PRODUCT TITLE</p>
        <p class="number">PARTnum</p>
        <p class="price">Price</p>
    </span>
    <a href="#" class="button">+ Add item</a>
    <a href="http://www.google.co.uk" class="qv"><img src="images/qv.png" width="17" height="17" /></a>
</div></li>
</ul>
</div>
</form>
```

**CSS:**

```
#specialOffer, #flyout1, #flyout2, #flyout3 {margin:0; padding:0; width:990px; overflow:hidden;}
#specialOffer {padding:10px 0 0 20px;}
#flyout1 {background:transparent url(../images/popupBG0.png) top left no-repeat;}

#specialOffer UL, UL.paginate-1, UL.paginate-2, UL.paginate-3 {
    float:left;
    margin:0; padding:0;
    height:260px;
    display:block;
}
#specialOffer UL {width:970px;}
#specialOffer UL, UL.paginate-3 {
    height:270px;
}
#specialOffer UL LI, UL.paginate-1 LI, UL.paginate-2 LI, UL.paginate-3 LI {
    float:left;
    margin:30px 30px 0 27px; padding:0;
    display:inline;
    width:130px;
    height:200px;
}
#specialOffer UL LI {
    height:220px;
}

#scrollable {
    margin-top:10px;
    float:left;
    background-color:#eee;
    width:990px;
    border-top: 1px;
    border-top-color: #CCC;
    border-top-style: solid;
}

.pager {
  margin-right:10px;
  overflow:hidden;
  padding:1em 0;
  float:right;
}

.pager li{
  float:left;
  list-style-type:none;
  margin-right:.3em;
  font-size:1.1em;
}

.pager a{
  color:#FF9182;
  outline:none;
  text-decoration:underline;
}
.pager a:hover{
  text-decoration:none;
}
.pager .active a {
 color:#666;
 font-weight:bold;
}

.pager .disabled {
 width:32px;
 text-indent:-9999px;
}

/* Needed for carousel*/
.flexiwrap {
  margin:0 0 0 20px; padding:0;
  float:left;
  width:970px;
  height:271px;
}

/* PAGINATED CONTENT */
#Prod1, #Prod2, #Prod3, #subProd {float:left; margin:0; padding:0; width:130px;}
#Prod4 {float:left; margin:0; padding:0; width:130px;}
#Prod1 img.thumb, #Prod2 img.thumb,
#Prod3 img.thumb, #subProd img.thumb {
    margin:0; padding:0 10px;
    background-color:#fff;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
}

.button, .qv {
    float:left;
    background-image: linear-gradient(#ffffff, #eeeeee);
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 3px;
    color: #666;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 17px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    text-decoration:none;
    overflow: visible;
}
.qv {
    z-index:9999px;
}
#Prod1 .qv, #Prod2 .qv,
#Prod3 .qv, #subProd .qv {
    float:right;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding:5px 5px 0px 6px;
}
#Prod1 .qv IMG, #Prod2 .qv IMG,
#Prod3 .qv IMG, #subProd .qv IMG {
    border:0 none;
    margin:0; padding:0;
}

#Prod1 .product P, #Prod2 .product P,
#Prod3 .product P, #subProd .product P {margin:5px 0; padding:0; line-height:13px;}
#Prod1 .product .title, #Prod2 .product .title,
#Prod3 .product .title, #subProd .product .title {color:#666; font-size:13px;}
#Prod1 .product .number, #Prod2 .product .number,
#Prod3 .product .number, #subProd .product .number {color:#666; font-size:11px;}
#Prod1 .product .price, #Prod2 .product .price,
#Prod3 .product .price, #subProd .product .price {
    font-size:20px;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin-bottom:3px;
    line-height:20px;
}

#close {margin-top:-15px;}
#close a {float:right; margin:0; padding:0; text-decoration:none;}

#Prod1, #Prod2, #Prod3 {border:1px solid #ccc; height:110px; cursor:pointer;}
#prodDoll INPUT, #prodOutfit INPUT, #prodAcc INPUT {display:none;}
#Prod4 {float:left; margin:0; padding:0; width:130px; height:110px; cursor:pointer;}
#subProd {cursor: pointer;}
```

**JS:**

```
$('#flyout1').hide();
$('#prodSubmit').hide();

$('#flyout1 #subProd').click(function() {
    var id1 = $(this).attr('class');
    $("#catnum1").val(id1);  
    $("#Prod1").html($("." + $(this).attr('class')).html());
    $("#Prod1").css("border", "none");
    $("#prodD #close").css("display", "block");
    $("#prodD .button, #prodD .qv").css("display", "none");
    $("#Prod1").attr('rel', 'done');
});

$("#prodD #close a").click(function() {
    $("#prodD #close").css("display", "none");
    $("#Prod1").empty();
    $("#Prod1").css("border", "1px solid #CCC");
    $("#Prod1").removeAttr("rel")
});

$("#Prod1").on("click",function(){
    $("#flyout1").slideToggle();
});

$("a.qv").click(function(e) { e.stopPropagation(); });
$("a.qv").colorbox();
```

I've re-used a previous `JSFiddle`, as the functionality behind the page is more or less the same.

Comment: "I've tried a LOT of different ways and just can't seem to get them to work." So, what have you tried?

Comment: Cookies maybe ? Or you could also store informations in $_SESSION using ajax on the right events.

Comment: You can try to save state through cookies, though cookies really can't store alot of data.  Are you using server side technologies (C#, php, java)? If so I'd recommend that you look into session variables.

Comment: @roasted I've tried various methods employing cookies, I've tried localStorage via HTML5. I think trying to store an entire DIV is a little taxing

Comment: @Virus721 does $_SESSION exist outside of PHP? :/

Comment: ->Glatuhii : Glasses do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Cookies** are used to maintain state in a webpage between visits. Refer to http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp for how to use them.

I'm not clear with what you mean by "the point they have reached". I can suggest how you should employ the cookies if you clarify what you're after.

Comment: Basically a user clicks from a selection of products and they are added to the DIV at the top of the page (illustrated by the grey outlines), however, if you use has to leave the page, the progress is lost. I need a way to record the progress (for the length of the session at least) of the user, i.e. how many products/options they have clicked etc I've experiemnted briefly with cookies, but have had little luck, anyone who can steer me in the right direction will be teaching me something new :)

Comment: I've approached this from another direction, thank you for everyone's help

Comment: Glad you found your answer

Comment: Simon Robb: I eventually went back to cookies. Thank you for your pointers. I thought I could do this by appending the URL in a page anchor style (hashtags).

It was very hard for me to clarify what I wanted as I don't think I really knew myself, your references to cookies REALLY helped. And I mean that, I learned something today, thank you.

Comment: @Darren good to hear :) appreciate you taking the time to say thanks! good luck